# Do moderators lack sense of humour?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, moderation

Beyond the provocative title, I'd actually be interested in how flags on answers are treated by moderators, and how does a moderator decide to mark a flag as helpful or decline it. Here's what happened.

Yesterday, I flagged this answer : [Highcharts : Chart with drilldown how to obtain click event of drill up button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489480/highcharts-chart-with-drilldown-how-to-obtain-click-event-of-drill-up-button/26544101#26544101)

(the answer has been deleted since then)

This answer was something like

> sadfsadfasdfsdfsafsadfsdafsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfasdfasdfsafsadfsadfsafsadfsadfsdfsafsdfsafsafsdfsafsadfsadfsadfsadfsadfsadfsdafsdafadasdfasfsdfsadfsadfsdfsdfsdfsdafsadfsdfsdfsdfsdfsadfsadfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdafsadfasfsdfsadfasdfasdfsadfasdfasdfasdfsdafadsf

You know, the typical new user trying to see how posting an answer works.

In my comment to the moderator, I found it funny to put that comment

> dsfsdafsdfdsfsdfsdfadsfsdaf :D

This flag was declined, even though the original post was clearly garbage (and has been removed).

Now, I know being a moderator is not a easy duty, and I understand my comment can be seen as noisy as the answer I originally flagged. I would even understand that my comment caused even more harm than the original post since it entered a queue only reviewed by a very small set of persons.

However, I'd be grateful if a moderator could shed some light on what happened in that particular case. Was my flag declined because the attached comment was not even remotely funny? Did the moderator only see my comment, and not the post it was related to? Was it just human mistake, and a too quick click on <kbd>Decline</kbd> rather than on <kbd>Accept</kbd>?

Comment: dsasfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsf ????

Comment: The post was deleted from review, meaning that no moderator was involved in handling your flag. It was probably marked declined because reviewers mostly picked a different reason to remove it (it was marked as spam by some), leading to an *entirely automatic* declined flag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Custom flags don't get auto-dismissed by review actions. So this leaves an already-handled answer in our queue with a gibberish custom flag on it. That's a *very* constructive and productive use of our time.

Comment: @animuson: right, I hadn't quite put two and two together and realise that it must've been a custom flag. Need more caffeine, obviously.

Comment: Don't wake the sleeping dogs. You can't expect sense of humor when doing so. There are enough serious reasons, they'll have to work on :P ...

Comment: Do the posters all have only one working keyboard row?

Comment: I can see your intentions with the humour, but see it from the other side as a Mod. They go to your flag and see *Reason for flag: `dsfsdafsdfdsfsdfsdfadsfsdaf :D`*, they think *WTF*, and reject. Effectively you did exactly the same as the answer you were flagging, so the Moderator just denied based on the same reasons you denied (flagged) the answer in the first place. Therefore the Mod did what you did, and so it's your fault...

Comment: Don't waste the moderator's time. What is funny for you is a waste of their time and energy. Of course they don't find it funny when people make their job harder.

Comment: Why would you flag that hilarious answer? Don't *you* have a sense of humor? ;p

Comment: I think this is a valid question (despite, perhaps, a bit misguided) and don't think it deserves so many downvotes.. but whatever. You Meta.SO folk are really doing a good job getting rid of the harshness!

Comment: @Seth - I more or less abandoned Meta due to the insular, pedantic harshness.  And yet I keep getting sucked back in on occasion.  Maybe if I had the option to hide that 'Featured on Meta' sidebar I could kick the habit for good.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When you use a custom moderator flag, the explanation you provide should contain:

1. A description of the problem, and
2. What you want the moderator to do about it.

In this particular case, a suitable response would have been "Gibberish."  But you provided gibberish in the flag itself, rather than an explanation.

I have seen a number of extremely humorous moderator flags.  A couple of individuals were masters at this; they would make me laugh, but still get the point across.  Yours does neither. :)

Comment: "There once was a question from Stack Overflow / But it was only so-so / and sent to sharepoint / but yet dissapoints / and was sent back here a long time ago. // Please delete this question" ([poetry of flagging](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/conversation/poetry-of-flagging))

Comment: There was no need for a custom moderator flag for this at all, right? I always flag these types of answers with the generic "not an answer" flag, and they normally get deleted very quickly.

Comment: "Not an Answer" would have worked here.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I don't think that a mod would have disputed a VLQ flag on it either (that would have kicked it into the VLQ queue where 6x recommends or 3x 20k delete votes would have deleted it without a mod needing to get involved).

Comment: Also, the NAA and VLQ queues are currently around 140 and 60 flags respectively, so adding to one of those queues will be handled much more quickly. The "Other" flag queue is around 1300. We really don't like it when people add to that without a clear reason.

Comment: @MichaelT I believe NAA flags also push the answer into the LQ review queue. I would have to dig out the details, but from memory I think that moderators *can* handle the NAA flags, but they automatically go to the LQ review queue as well (?).

Comment: @RetoKoradi NAA feed into LQ queue since [2014-04-22](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/165773): "VLQ and NAA flags on posts that have not been previously reviewed and are not closed, deleted, locked or accepted will enter /review/low-quality-posts..."

Comment: Also, I should add that spammers and trolls often leave gibberish flags on their spam in a further attempt to promote it. I've even seen some "plz answer me" flags devolve into gibberish as they try to annoy moderators into answering their questions. Therefore, we're primed to decline gibberish flags because very rarely are they useful.

Comment: BilltheLizard QFT - TBH my POV is, ATM, AFAIK, NAA and VLQ are low, OFQ high. FWIW pls TAI. HTH

Comment: "But you provided gibberish in the flag itself, rather than an explanation" - In other words, yes, moderators lack a sense of humor and will not spend time trying to parse your tongue-in-cheek explanations.

Answer (score 16):

I'm no moderator, but...why are you spamming the mods, too?

You should be very explicit and clear as to why you're flagging something; there's no reason to *not* be, as moderators should only ever get involved [under dire circumstances](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

I can't speak on their behalf, but I wouldn't give a flag that had that kind of message a second thought, as it doesn't seem sincere or serious, nor does it seem to alert me to a pressing issue.  I'd think it were some other spammer trying to get a rise out of the moderator team.

Comment: I'd quite understand that if the queue that moderators see only consists of flags' comments. But wouldn't it make sense that they are shown the post the flag relates too? And in that case, wouldn't my really non-funny comment deserve some mercy?

Comment: @Alexis, no, no mercy :P [*Off with his head!*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eobuu-IexvI)

Comment: @AlexisPigeon - can't speak on behalf of SO moderators either, but my opinion as moderator on some forums and chatrooms : Adding the post content to the Flag comment just add more text to read, and drasticaly increase the amout of time required to sort things out. We need to take the appropriate move in the shortest delay, so, be specific and straightforward. The more since half of the flags are "false positive" but some _very not so funny kids testing wether we are on duty or sleeping..._

Comment: @AlexisPigeon - so, it's not a lack of humour, we do have humour, but humour is appropriate when you have time to enjoy it, not when you have 400 issues queued and need to handle them within the next hour... (Edit : I laughed on your comment to the moderator though, really :D But I had time to enjoy it; that's the only difference and has nothing to do with a lack of humour)

Answer (score 4):

Alas, as a moderator, I do not have as much fun. I don't even get to politely abuse spammers so badly they self delete their answers. I need to do it myself! OH THE HORROR.

More seriously though, moderators have a *ton* of flags to go through. While it might be funny once, the 20th time, it just gets tiring. If you're going to be funny, at least do it right. Something like *catlike typing detected* - User has posted a ton of gibberish, may be more appropriate.

I'd save humour for less important avenues like chat